# git rebase to remove a commit

Tags: git, repository, gerrit

I have the following change history in my git repository:

```
---X---Y---Z---A---B---C
```

I began working from a base of code Z and made three changes A, B and C. Each of these changes has been uploaded as separate reviews on Gerrit and each depends on the change before it.

Following a review I want to remove change A, so that my change history is:

```
---X---Y---Z---B---C
```

What is the correct flow of `git rebase -i` and `git commit` to get this to work?

I assumed the following:

1. Use `git rebase -i HEAD~3` to show the last three commits. This shows the file contents:

   `pick 1234567 Commit A message`
   `pick 1a2b3c4 Commit B message`
   `pick abcdefg Commit C message`
2. I can then delete the first line and save the file to remove the first commit.
3. This is where I get stuck... If I try to `git commit --amend` I can only amend the commit of C. I thus don't know how to push my rebase change to Gerrit for review using `repo upload .` or `git push`

I am using Gerrit 2.2 so there is no rebase button on the review page.

Comment: there is no step 3. you are done...

Comment: Edited step 3 to make it clearer where my problem is. Basically how do I then push rebase change or B and C to Gerrit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following steps have now worked for me:

1. Use git rebase -i HEAD~3 to show the last three commits. This shows the file contents:

   `pick 1234567 Commit A message`
   `pick 1a2b3c4 Commit B message`
   `pick abcdefg Commit C message`
2. I can then delete the first line and save the file to remove the first commit.
3. A `git log` now shows my B and C change after the base of Z, with their new SHA-1 values
4. I can then push each change individually to their respective reviews:

   `git push ssh://myserver:29418/project SHA1_of_B:ref/changes/123`
   `git push ssh://myserver:29418/project SHA1_of_C:ref/changes/789`

Where `123` and `789` are the review numbers for change B and C respectively. My B and C changes each have new patches which are properly rebased.

Turns out my problem was just understanding that I had to `git push` both changes individually.

Comment: there are two `markus` users that signed in just a few weeks before?

Answer (score 1):

After Step 2) you're done with rebasing. After choosen which commits to pick. It is possible that you get merge conflicts. Fix them with `git mergetool` and do a `git rebase --continue`

EDIT: Because rebasing does change the history. I don't know how gerrit will react on this. You can try to add the force flag e.g. `git push -f`, but remember this is dangerous because of history change!

Comment: And how do I push these changes to the dependencies of B and C to Gerrit for review?