# How to remove specific commits from remote repo

Tags: git

I have a remote repo with 7 total commits (let's call them A - G, with G being the most recent commit). Commits C and E didn't actually warrant a brand new commit, and I'd like to remove them from the remote commit  history all while keeping commit G as HEAD. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to squash commits in git after they have been pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667884/how-to-squash-commits-in-git-after-they-have-been-pushed)

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11955118/1506009 - The interactive git rebase is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) says the following about this:

---

A range of commits could also be removed with rebase. If we have the following situation:

```
E---F---G---H---I---J  topicA
```

then the command

```
git rebase --onto topicA~5 topicA~3 topicA
```

would result in the removal of commits F and G:

```
E---H'---I'---J'  topicA
```

This is useful if F and G were flawed in some way, or should not be part of topicA. Note that the argument to --onto and the  parameter can be any valid commit-ish.

---

**BUT** this applies only the local repo in the first place. So when pushing this **modified** commit history to your *remote*, you need to have sufficient privileges to do so. See [force push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--f) for more details. I can tell you from my own experience, that this can be an issue in MS TFS.