# Git deleting branch

Tags: git, branch

Lets say I have a **main** branch, which I take a branch of to work on **Feature 1**

Main -> **Feature 1**

I then branch off **Feature 1** to create **Feature 1 extended**

**Feature 1** -> **Feature 1 extended**

Question 1 : After merging **Feature 1** to main, can the remote **Feature 1** branch be deleted *before* **Feature 1 extended** is merged into **main**? is **Feature 1 extended** dependent on the remote **Feature 1** branch existing?

Question 2 : If I decide I don't want **Feature 1**, but I do want **Feature 1 extended**, can I delete the remote **Feature 1** branch *before* merging in **Feature 1 extended**?

I've done some tests, and it appears that it's ok to delete the remote **Feature 1** branch in both cases, but I was wondering if there are any gotchas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1 : After merging Feature 1 to main, can the remote Feature 1 branch be deleted before Feature 1 extended is merged into main? is Feature 1 extended dependent on the remote Feature 1 branch existing?

You can safely delete *feature1* branch, *feature1extended* does not "depend" on *feature1* branch.

A branch is a pointer to a commit which itself point to ancestors commit. When you remove a branch, if another branch refers to a commit which has commits of the former in its ancestors, these commits are still reachable.

Note that you might want to **rebase** *feature1extended* on *main* so that *feature1extended* appears as being branched off *main*.

> Question 2 : If I decide I don't want Feature 1, but I do want Feature 1 extended, can I delete the remote Feature 1 branch *before* merging in Feature 1 extended?

You can but same explanation as above will still apply and commits of *feature1* will appear in *feature1extended*.

To "forget" commits of *feature1*, you'll have to use [`rebase onto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914052/how-to-git-rebase-a-branch-with-the-onto-command) or [interactive rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954635/git-rebase-to-remove-a-commit) for example.